# How can I show the msn user picture in Empathy?

Tags: empathy, msn

In Empathy, I can use the default image in google talk. But, with msn, the picture didn't show. How can I config it to make it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Empathy do the following:

`Edit -> Personal Information`

In **Account** Select the MSN account. After that click on the **ICON** to the right. Select the picture you want. Thats it.